# Can't train SVM with FFT data which is complex

Tags: python-3.x, fft, svm, complex-numbers

I am using python and I am training svm model on fft data. But fft returns complex numbers and  as i heard svm does not work with complex numbers. Is there any way that i can convert complex numbers to float or train svm with complex numbers?

I tried to convert complex to float but it simply does not work and i tried to train svm with complex numbers but in vain

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly train an SVM on multiple features.
In your case you have a pair of orthogonal features: the real & complex parts.
Just separate them and present them as inputs.

Alternatively, you may find that a scalar like
RMS power makes sense for your application domain.
In that case, for a number R + Cj, you would construct a new feature using:

```
power = math.sqrt(R*R + C*C)
```